# How do I use one request for multiple tests in Postman?

Tags: api, postman

I have an API in the body of which I write for example:

```
{
"email": "{{email}}",
"age": 18,
"phone": "+000000000000"
}
```

I want to write tests to check:

1. Check that I get an answer of 200 when I create a new user
2. Check if I get a response of 400 when I create a new user with an email that already exists
3. Verify that I get a 502 response when I create a new user without a phone number

If I write tests that check for error 200 and for error 400 then one of them will always fail

How can I write these tests if I only do one request? Do I need to create a separate request for each test?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is necessary to create separate requests for each result. In Postman, each request returns a single status. You can't check statuses 200,400 and 502 in one request.

For 200 and 502, only requests should be made with body.

For the 400 test, you should create a successful user in the pre-request, send the request with the same e-mail in the body and see the error.